# Perl or Python SVN Crawler

Tags: python, perl, svn, web-crawler

Is there an SVN crawler, that can walk thru an SVN repo and spitt out all existing branches, or tags?

Preferably in Perl or Python ...

Answer (score 6):

SVN tags and branches are just directories, usually following a particular naming convention.  You can easily get them in perl like:

```
my @branches = `svn ls YourRepoBaseURL/branches`;
chomp @branches; # remove newlines
chop @branches; # remove trailing /
my @tags = `svn ls YourRepoBaseURL/tags`;
chomp @tags;
chop @tags;
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, but not quiet what I need ...

We have a huge repo with hundreds of projects, each having their own ttb structure, so I need to traverse thru it and find all the open branches ...
But this gives me a starting point in perl ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little snippet to print information about files in a SVN repository in **python**:

```
# svncrawler.py
import os
import sys
import pysvn

svn_client = pysvn.Client()

for file_status in svn_client.status(sys.argv[1]):
    print u'SVN File %s %s' % (file_status, file_status.text_status)
```

Call it like this:

```
python svncrawler.py my_repository
```

It should be easy to modify it to just print the tags and branches.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, here is what I came up with in python with your help:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
import pysvn
svnclient = pysvn.Client()
projects = svnclient.list(sys.argv[1])
for project_path, project_info in projects:
    try:
        project_branches = svnclient.list(project_path.path + '/branches/')
        if ( len(project_branches)>2 ):
            for branch, info in project_branches:
                print branch.path
    except:
        pass
```